# Query existing database with peewee - MySQL metastore

Tags: python, mysql, peewee

I am new to peewee and am trying to query the MySQL metastore db used by my Hive installation. I was able to list all the tables available, but am not able to query a particular table 'TBLS'. This is a standard metastore table that just stores info on all tables in the metastore.

This is my code till date :

```
from peewee import *
metastore_db = MySQLDatabase("metastore", host="localhost", port=3306, user="root", passwd="")
metastore_db.connect()

tables = metastore_db.get_tables()
for tbl in tables:
     print tbl
```

Now to query the table I wrote :

```
class BaseModel(Model):
    class Meta:
            database = metastore_db

class TBLS(BaseModel):
    DB_ID = IntegerField()
    OWNER = CharField()
    TBL_NAME = CharField()

    class Meta:
            db_table = 'TBLS'

tbl = TBLS.select()
for t in tbl:
    print t
```

Now I get this error -

**peewee.OperationalError: (1054, "Unknown column 't1.id' in 'field list'")**

What am I missing, or is this because the table name in is uppercase? Do I need to mention ALL the columns in the Model?

This is the structure of the TBLS table -

```
mysql> desc TBLS;
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field              | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| TBL_ID             | bigint(20)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| CREATE_TIME        | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| DB_ID              | bigint(20)   | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| LAST_ACCESS_TIME   | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| OWNER              | varchar(767) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| RETENTION          | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| SD_ID              | bigint(20)   | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| TBL_NAME           | varchar(128) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| TBL_TYPE           | varchar(128) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| VIEW_EXPANDED_TEXT | mediumtext   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| VIEW_ORIGINAL_TEXT | mediumtext   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Thank you!

```
====================================================
EDIT: and UPDATE
====================================================
```

I was able to remove the error by adding some more Meta info like such -

```
class tbls(BaseModel):
                tbl_id             = PrimaryKeyField(db_column='TBL_ID')
                create_time        = IntegerField(db_column='CREATE_TIME')
                db_id              = IntegerField(db_column='DB_ID')
                last_access_time   = IntegerField(db_column='LAST_ACCESS_TIME')
                owner              = CharField(max_length=767,db_column='OWNER')
                retention          = IntegerField(db_column='RETENTION')
                sd_id              = IntegerField(db_column='SD_ID')
                tbl_name           = CharField(max_length=128,db_column='TBL_NAME')
                tbl_type           = CharField(max_length=128,db_column='TBL_TYPE')
                class Meta:
                        db_table = 'TBLS'


tbl = tbls.select()

for t in tbl:
    print t.owner,t.tbl_name
```

Now I can retrieve the rows needed. My question is, how can I get all the columns of a table without having to explicitly name each ( like a select *), if that's possible.